# How to extract punctuations only using regexp_extract function in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am learning regexp_extract function in hive suppose I have table 'A' with column 'word' as,

`A
word
Hello!
world,
how 
are 
you?`

I want to extract punctuations only so that output will be,

`!
,
?`

How to do this with regexp_extract I tried as follows but did not get desired output,

`select regexp_extract(word,"[^A-Za-z0-9]*","1") from A;`

Please Guide!

Comment: Forcing a solution ("How to do this with regexp_extract") is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hive> with A as (select explode(array('word','Hello!','world,','how','are','you?')) as word)
    > select  regexp_extract(word,'\\p{Punct}',0) as Punct
    > from    A
    > ;
OK
punct

!
,


?
```

Comment: Hey Dudu you did it again,my problem is solved.Thank you!

Comment: Dudu, could you please recommend any simple document or site where I can understand which regex pattern to use as per the requirement.

Comment: Hive uses Java regex https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html **P.s. (1)** the 3rd argument of REGEXP_EXTRACT is the index of the capturing group (a part of the matching pattern that is surrounded by brackets)  or **0** for the whole pattern. **(2)** `*` stands for zero or more, therefor your pattern matches zero length strings.